# loop through Javascript object that has an array as a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

My object looks like this

```
{
  "about.php": [
    "#topNav",
    "#botNav",
    "#employees"
  ],
    "index.php": [
    "#blah"
  ]
}
```

I am looping through it like so

```
        var validation_messages = obj;

            for (var key in validation_messages) {
               if (validation_messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                   var obj = validation_messages[key];
                    for (var prop in obj) {
                      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                        console.log(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
                      }
                   }
                }
            }
```

I am getting this result

```
0 = #topNav
1 = #botNav
2 = #employees
0 = #blah
```

I need the name of the object key not the key of the array that is in the objects value. like so:

```
about.php = #topNav
about.php = #botNav
about.php = #employees
index.php = #blah
```

I will be pushing new values into the arrays if they do not exists like so:

```
{
  "about.php": [
    "#topNav",
    "#botNav",
    "#employees"
  ],
    "index.php": [
    "#blah",
    "#newValue"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over the second structure incorrectly. It is an array, not an object.

```
for (var key in validation_messages) {
    if (validation_messages.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var obj = validation_messages[key];

        // use a for loop here instead of for...in
        for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
            console.log(key + " = " + obj[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2gac98xe/)